# Computing Fundamental Group of $S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I have a hard time in understanding this from books and papers I found online. So anyone please suggest me some good reference or preferably an online lecture for computation of fundamental group of $S^1$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [Algebraic topology](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) by A. Hatcher? See **Theorem 1.7.* on page 29.

Answer (score 0):

I'll supply the first proof I ever saw of this fact. Denote by $p:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ the projection $p(z)=[z]$, where we have identified $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}=S^1$.

**Lemma:** Let $f:S^1\to S^1$ be continuous, then we may find a unique lift $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $pg(z)=fp(z)$, and we have that $g(z+1)=g(z)+n_f$ for some integer $n_f$.

We prove that such a lift exists by showing that the domain on which it can be defined is the entire space $\mathbb{R}$. By augmenting $f(z)+t$ we may assume that $f(0)=1/2$. Let $U$ be the connected component of $0$ in $f^{-1}((0, 1))$. Define $g:U\to \mathbb{R}$ by $g([z])=z$ where $z$ is chosen to be in $[0, 1)$. Let $V=\{z|$ there exists connected open neighborhood of $z$, $V_z$, there is a is a lift $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g|_{V_z\cap U}=h|_{V_z\cap U}$$\}$. If $V=\mathbb{R}$, we are done. We have just shown that $V\neq \varnothing$. By constuction, $V$ is open. We must show that it is closed, and then $V$ is a clopen nonempty set in $\mathbb{R}$, and thus is $\mathbb{R}$. Let $x_n\to x$ where $x_n\in V$. Let $f_n:V_n\to \mathbb{R}$ be the lifts. We have that $f_n(z)-f_m(z)\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $f_n(0)-f_m(0)=0$, so that $f_n(z)=f_m(z)$ since the neighborhood of definition is connected. Denote the common function as $f$. Then define $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}(f(x_n))$. We can lift to a neighborhood of $x$ using the same method as above, and so we have that $x\in V$ and $V=\mathbb{R}$ as desired. This implies that a lift exists and we are done.

**Lemma:** The assignment $f\mapsto n_f$ defines a mapping of abelian groups, $deg:\pi_1(S^1)\to \mathbb{Z}$.

We need to show that if $f$ is homotopic to $g$, then $n_f=n_g$. Let $h$ be a homotopy between them. The same aurguement implies that $h:S^1\times I\to S^1$, can be lifted to $g:\mathbb{R}\times I\to \mathbb{R}$, with $p(g(z, t))=h(p(z), t)$. This implies that $g(1, t)-g(0, t)$ is an integer, and since it is continous as a function of $t$, we have that it is constant. Since $n_g=g(1, 1)-g(0, 1)=g(1, 0)-g(0, 0)=n_f$, $deg$ is indeed well-defined. It is clearly a homomorphism, since if $f, g:S^1\to S^1$ are lifted by $f', g':\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, then $f+g$ is lifted by $f'+g'$.

**Theorem:** $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$.

We will show that $deg$ is an isomorphism. It is surjective, since we can take the map $n:S^1\to S^1$ given by $z\mapsto nz$, which is clearly lifted by $n:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, which has $n*1-n*0=n$. Since $deg$ is an additive map, we only have to show that $Ker(deg)=0$. Let $f:S^1\to S^1$ be a map such that $deg(f)=0$. Let $g:\mathbb{R}^1\to \mathbb{R}^1$ be a lift of $f$. We have thus that $g(z)=g(z+1)$, or that we may define $g:S^1\to \mathbb{R}^1$. We can now construct a nullhomotopy of $f$ by $h(z, t)=p(tg(z))$. Thus $[f]=0$, and $deg$ is injective and surjective, so that $deg$ is an isomorphism.